# Stripe webhook account.updated never triggered, whenever an connected account status changes

Tags: stripe-payments

I have a Stripe Connect integration with custom account.
When I create a Custom account, the account status is "Restricted". Then I fill the onboarding form and it changes to "Complete" (ready for payments and payouts).

Even though I have a webhook setup for the `account.updated` event, it's never triggered.

Following [Stripe documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/webhooks) it should be triggered for all the connected account, whenever a status changes.
[image]

However, as we can see here, no event was triggered since one week:
[image]

Do you have an idea why? (please note that I'm in test mode right now)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Is your webhook endpoint a [Connect webhook endpoint](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/webhooks)? There are 2 types. I would make sure this webhook endpoint was created as a Connect one. If it is and you've configured it for `account.updated` events, then I would reach out to Stripe's support to see what's going on.

Comment: OMG, no it was not... Thank you so much, I didn't see the check when creating the webhook. Thank you very much

Comment: weird that the documentation doesn't seem to mention this. I was following 'collection-then-transfer-guide' and nothing was said. thank you very much

Comment: There's not even as much as a warning when you try to add events to the normal webhook